# Correct way of Dropping and Recreating Core Data Store

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

I wanted to confirm that my method of dropping a Core Data store (sqlite) is correct. It seems to work without crashing but wanted to confirm this is the correct method. Afterwards when the user connects to the database a new sqlite file is generated automatically.

Here is my code to drop data store:

```
 - (BOOL)dropDataStore{
 // ----------------------
 // This method removes all traces of the Core Data store
 // ----------------------

 NSError *_error = nil;
 NSURL *_storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store.sqlite"];
 NSPersistentStore *_store = [persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:_storeURL];

 // Remove the SQL store and the file associated with it
 if ([persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:_store error:&_error]) {
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:_storeURL.path error:&_error];
 }

 if (_error) {
 return NO;
 }

 persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
 managedObjectContext = nil;
 managedObjectModel = nil;

 return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good method.

At a minimum, SQLite on iOS 7 and up creates journal files in the same directory as its main file. If you leave those behind, you may get old data persisting into the new file, or corrupt data. So **at a minimum** you need to also remove `Store.sqlite-shm` and `Store.sqlite-wal`.

If your Core Data model uses binary attributes and has "allow external storage" enabled for any of those attributes, then values for those attributes may be stored in external files. Obviously your code wouldn't remove those, but the location of these files is not documented.

If you expect to need to remove Core Data persistent store files, you should really put the files into their own custom subdirectory instead of directly in the documents directory. Then, you can just recursively remove everything in that directory and not care whether Core Data is creating extra files outside of the persistent store file.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I have turned off journaling so the shm and wal files are not a problem. The only attributes in my model are float, dates and integers. The reason I am doing this is to give the user an option "Delete All Data'. I thought this method was clean as opposed to emptying the objects in each entity. With this additional information is my function sound? Thanks.

Comment: It's sound in that it actually removes the data. It's not sound in that turning off journaling is not actually a good idea. It's also a potential maintenance issue, in case later on journaling is enabled or you end up adding binary attributes to the model.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I turn off the journaling to keep all the data in one single file. This is useful for the user (and clear for them) when backing up using itunes file sharing to only backup one file. Yes in the future if binary attributes are used this won't be a valid solution. But for the current circumstance, can this method cause a crash or some other kind of corruption?

Comment: Isn't there any other standard way to drop journal files yet?

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard no, because Apple tries to help developers make their data **safer** not, **less safe**.